# Java's Method.isVarArgs() doesn't work with method in scala

Tags: scala

I'm new learner of scala. There is problem I can not resolve. I use java reflection to check a method which was written in scala.(I don't find proper way in scala)
codes like this:

```
case class SomeClass(udf: UDF) {
    // Get Method object of "eval" method in udf
    val evalMethod: Method = {
        var evalMethods: ListBuffer[Method] = new ListBuffer[Method]
        udf.getClass.getMethods.foreach(m => {
            if (m.getName().equals("eval")) {
                evalMethods += m
            }
        })
        if (evalMethods.length != 1) {
            throw new Exception(s"$udf must have only one eval method")
        }
        evalMethods(0)
    }

    val evalParamsType = {
        val hasVarArgs = evalMethod.isVarArgs // Not work here
        println("varargs:" + hasVarArgs) // Always false
        for (param <- evalMethod.getParameterTypes) {
            // do some thing
        }
        // return some thing
    }
}

trait UDF {
}

object SomeUDF extends UDF {
    def eval(fields: String*) = {
        // do something here
    }
}
```

The codes may looks weird, I have to use reflection to do this work, because "eval" method in UDF can have different parameters and return type. (That's another problem...)

It seems that Method class in java can not recognize varargs in scala, is there any way to do this work in java or scala?

Comment: Don't you need to assign hasVarArgs to either a val or a var first?

Comment: Oh, You are right, that's wrong edit, I'll fix it. The problem is not this, but still thanks

Comment: This whole thing looks suspicious. Why doing this at all? Ask you this question. The answer wil be "cos I want to do bla bla bla" google for "how to solve bla bla bla in scala" if you do not find it, ask on StackOverflow.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Scala's varargs encoding scheme is different from java.

```
// used :javap SomeUDF in scala repl
public void eval(scala.collection.Seq<java.lang.String>);
```

Scala uses `scala.collection.Seq`. Java uses `Array`.
You can use `@scala.annotation.varargs` to tell the compiler to generate a java varargs bridge method (will call the scala variant).

```
object SomeUDF extends UDF {
    @scala.annotation.varargs
    def eval(fields: String*) = {
        // do something here
    }
}
```

The scala repl javap output contains a java varargs method now.

```
public void eval(java.lang.String...)
```